# Unable to install foreman-installer on CentOS 6.6, what could be the reason?

Tags: puppet, centos6, foreman

I'm trying to install Puppet 3.x using Foreman-installer.

I've following [this guide](http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.9/index.html#3.InstallingForeman) after doing the following steps:

- Installed a clean installation of CentOS 6.6.
- Added foreman and puppet repos.
- Ran `yum update`

Next, I've made sure the relevant repos are enabled:

```
[root@dev5-puppet01 ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * epel: mirror.nonstop.co.il
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
repo id repo name    status
base CentOS-6 - Base   6,575                          
epel Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64          11,772
extras   CentOS-6 - Extras                                   35
foreman  Foreman 1.9                                         322
foreman-plugins  Foreman plugins 1.9                         173
puppetlabs-pc1   Puppet Labs PC1 Repository el 6 - x86_64    28
updates  CentOS-6 - Updates                                  254
repolist: 19,159
```

And issued the command to install `foreman-installer`:

```
[root@dev5-puppet01 ~]# yum install foreman-installer
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * epel: mirror.nonstop.co.il
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package foreman-installer.noarch 1:1.9.0-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem-kafo >= 0.6.5 for package: 1:foreman-installer-1.9.0-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem-apipie-bindings >= 0.0.6 for package: 1:foreman-installer-1.9.0-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem-highline for package: 1:foreman-installer-1.9.0-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby(abi) for package: 1:foreman-installer-1.9.0-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: foreman-selinux for package: 1:foreman-installer-1.9.0-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package foreman-selinux.noarch 0:1.9.0-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: policycoreutils-python for package: foreman-selinux-1.9.0-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/sbin/semanage for package: foreman-selinux-1.9.0-1.el6.noarch
---> Package ruby-libs.x86_64 0:1.8.7.374-4.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.5()(64bit) for package: ruby-libs-1.8.7.374-4.el6_6.x86_64
---> Package rubygem-apipie-bindings.noarch 0:0.0.13-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rest-client) < 1.8.0 for package: rubygem-apipie-bindings-0.0.13-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rest-client) >= 1.6.5 for package: rubygem-apipie-bindings-0.0.13-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(json) >= 1.2.1 for package: rubygem-apipie-bindings-0.0.13-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(oauth) for package: rubygem-apipie-bindings-0.0.13-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(awesome_print) for package: rubygem-apipie-bindings-0.0.13-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby(rubygems) for package: rubygem-apipie-bindings-0.0.13-1.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygem-highline.noarch 0:1.6.21-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-kafo.noarch 0:0.6.11-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(logging) < 2.0.0 for package: rubygem-kafo-0.6.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: puppet < 4.0.0 for package: rubygem-kafo-0.6.11-1.el6.noarch
Package puppet-2.7.26-2.el6.noarch is obsoleted by puppet-agent-1.2.2-1.el6.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(clamp) >= 0.6.2 for package: rubygem-kafo-0.6.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(powerbar) for package: rubygem-kafo-0.6.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(kafo_parsers) for package: rubygem-kafo-0.6.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/ruby for package: rubygem-kafo-0.6.11-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-readline5.x86_64 0:5.2-17.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package policycoreutils-python.x86_64 0:2.0.83-24.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsemanage-python >= 2.0.43-4 for package: policycoreutils-python-2.0.83-24.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: setools-libs-python for package: policycoreutils-python-2.0.83-24.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux-python for package: policycoreutils-python-2.0.83-24.el6.x86_64
---> Package ruby.x86_64 0:1.8.7.374-4.el6_6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-awesome_print.noarch 0:1.0.2-10.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-clamp.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-json.x86_64 0:1.4.6-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-kafo.noarch 0:0.6.11-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: puppet < 4.0.0 for package: rubygem-kafo-0.6.11-1.el6.noarch
Package puppet-2.7.26-2.el6.noarch is obsoleted by puppet-agent-1.2.2-1.el6.x86_64 which is already installed
---> Package rubygem-kafo_parsers.noarch 0:0.0.5-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rdoc) for package: rubygem-kafo_parsers-0.0.5-1.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygem-logging.noarch 0:1.8.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(multi_json) >= 1.8.4 for package: rubygem-logging-1.8.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(little-plugger) >= 1.1.3 for package: rubygem-logging-1.8.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygem-oauth.noarch 0:0.4.7-6.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-powerbar.noarch 0:1.0.11-8.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(ansi) < 1.5.0 for package: rubygem-powerbar-1.0.11-8.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(hashie) >= 1.1.0 for package: rubygem-powerbar-1.0.11-8.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(ansi) >= 1.4.0 for package: rubygem-powerbar-1.0.11-8.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygem-rest-client.noarch 0:1.6.7-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(mime-types) >= 1.16 for package: rubygem-rest-client-1.6.7-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(netrc) for package: rubygem-rest-client-1.6.7-2.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygems.noarch 0:1.3.7-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby-rdoc for package: rubygems-1.3.7-5.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libselinux-python.x86_64 0:2.0.94-5.8.el6 will be installed
---> Package libsemanage-python.x86_64 0:2.0.43-5.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package ruby-rdoc.x86_64 0:1.8.7.374-4.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby-irb = 1.8.7.374-4.el6_6 for package: ruby-rdoc-1.8.7.374-4.el6_6.x86_64
---> Package rubygem-ansi.noarch 0:1.4.3-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-hashie.noarch 0:2.0.5-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-kafo.noarch 0:0.6.11-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: puppet < 4.0.0 for package: rubygem-kafo-0.6.11-1.el6.noarch
Package puppet-2.7.26-2.el6.noarch is obsoleted by puppet-agent-1.2.2-1.el6.x86_64 which is already installed
---> Package rubygem-little-plugger.noarch 0:1.1.3-18.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-mime-types.noarch 0:1.16-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-multi_json.noarch 0:1.10.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-netrc.noarch 0:0.7.7-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-rdoc.x86_64 0:3.12-12.el6 will be installed
---> Package setools-libs-python.x86_64 0:3.3.7-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: setools-libs = 3.3.7-4.el6 for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsefs.so.4(VERS_4.0)(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libseaudit.so.4(VERS_4.2)(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libseaudit.so.4(VERS_4.1)(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpol.so.1(VERS_1.4)(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpol.so.1(VERS_1.3)(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpol.so.1(VERS_1.2)(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpoldiff.so.1(VERS_1.3)(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpoldiff.so.1(VERS_1.2)(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libapol.so.4(VERS_4.1)(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libapol.so.4(VERS_4.0)(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsefs.so.4()(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libseaudit.so.4()(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqpol.so.1()(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpoldiff.so.1()(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libapol.so.4()(64bit) for package: setools-libs-python-3.3.7-4.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ruby-irb.x86_64 0:1.8.7.374-4.el6_6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-kafo.noarch 0:0.6.11-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: puppet < 4.0.0 for package: rubygem-kafo-0.6.11-1.el6.noarch
Package puppet-2.7.26-2.el6.noarch is obsoleted by puppet-agent-1.2.2-1.el6.x86_64 which is already installed
---> Package setools-libs.x86_64 0:3.3.7-4.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rubygem-kafo-0.6.11-1.el6.noarch (foreman)
           Requires: puppet < 4.0.0
           Installed: puppet-agent-1.2.2-1.el6.x86_64 (@puppetlabs-pc1)
               puppet >= 4.0.0-1.el6
           Available: puppet-2.7.26-2.el6.noarch (epel)
               puppet = 2.7.26-2.el6
           Available: puppet-agent-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-pc1)
               puppet >= 4.0.0-1.el6
           Available: puppet-agent-1.0.1-1.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-pc1)
               puppet >= 4.0.0-1.el6
           Available: puppet-agent-1.1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-pc1)
               puppet >= 4.0.0-1.el6
           Available: puppet-agent-1.1.1-1.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-pc1)
               puppet >= 4.0.0-1.el6
           Available: puppet-agent-1.2.0-1.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-pc1)
               puppet >= 4.0.0-1.el6
           Available: puppet-agent-1.2.1-1.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-pc1)
               puppet >= 4.0.0-1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@dev5-puppet01 ~]#
```

Running the command with "--skip-broken" didn't help.

Edit #1:

```
[root@dev5-puppet01 ~]# rpm -qa | grep puppet                                                                                                                                                                                          
puppetlabs-release-pc1-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
```

What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you add the output of the following command `rpm -qa | grep puppet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem.

I was using `puppetlabs-release-pc1-el-6` repository instead of the right one which is `puppetlabs-release-el-6`.

The release packages were taken from:
https://yum.puppetlabs.com/

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also happen if hostname and host file is not provided on the machine

/etc/hosts
/etc/hostname